# Abstand, Entfernung, Strecke und Distanz: do they imply the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, difference

I am currently studying physics in German and these words came across and I have looked up these words in dictionary and they all have the meaning *distance*. I have seen *der Abstand* in other contexts but never encountered other words (even *Distanz*) would there be a huge difference among these words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Strecke** usually means "part of a way" with start and end point. It could be also understood as "the way to take".

The term is used in a wider sense by some phrases, such as "xxx bleibt auf der Strecke", which means "xxx is left behind".

**Abstand** is the word typically used when you are the outside observer. It describes the distance between the start point and the end point of a "Strecke", Most people use the term for short, directly measurable distances only. It relates both to space ("Abstand der Möbel") and time ("Abstand der Läufer").

**Entfernung** is most commonly used for "distance to travel", so you try to rank the position of something else in relation to your own position.

**Distanz** means the same as "Entfernung", but is more often used in negative formulations, like "die Distanz halten" (keeping the distance).

The [German Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite) has pretty good explanations.

Comment: Mit der Erläuterung zu _Strecke_ bin ich nicht so glücklich. Erstens ist der geometrische Begriff auf Englisch _line segment_; zweitens wird _Strecke_ in nicht so strengem Sprachgebrauch auch für _Länge einer Strecke_ benutzt.

Comment: @chirlu: genau, denn diese nicht-mathematische Bedeutung bleibt auf der *Strecke* - the answer should be extendend by an [edit].

Comment: Danke für die Kommentare, Änderungen sind eingepflegt.

Comment: Note that a *Strecke* does not need to be a straight line like *Abstand*. If used in *Rennstrecke* for example, it is most explicitly curved.

Comment: Careful here: In the mathematical definition _Strecke_ actually is the shortest path between two fixed points. So when used in a physics context, _Strecke_ actually implies a straight line (depending on the definition of _straight_ in the used geometry). In common language however, sthaightness is not required to call something _Strecke_.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some additions to what troeger wrote.

**Abstand**:

- "Der Abstand zwischen der Absprunglinie und der mit feuchtem Sand gefüllten Sprunggrube muss zwischen ein und drei Meter betragen - (...)" ([Wikipedia article "Weitsprung"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitsprung#Wettkampfbestimmungen))
- "Wie groß ist der Abstand zwischen beiden Punkten ungefähr?" (context: mathematics; ["Abstand zwischen Punkten, Geraden und Ebenen", Mathematrix.de](http://www.mathematrix.de/abstand-punkt-gerade-ebene/))

**Distanz** is also used in sports, to refer to the distance that people run, swim, ride, etc. Examples:

- "Kusch auf 100-Meter-Distanz WM-Achter" (discipline: swimming; [sport.de, 12.12.2016](http://www.sport.de/news/ne2542173/kusch-auf-100-meter-distanz-wm-achter/))
- "Europameister Sebastian Kienle hat seinen dritten WM-Titel über die halbe Ironman-Distanz knapp verpasst." ([sport1.de, 04.09.2016](http://www.sport1.de/triathlon/2016/09/sebastian-kienle-verpasst-titel-bei-triathlon-wm-knapp))
- "Distanz" is also used in the terms Distanzreiten & Distanzritt(e), which [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distanzreiten) defines as "ein Pferdesport, in dem es darum geht, eine große Entfernung zu Pferd so schnell wie möglich zu überwinden". Example sentence:

  - "Wie Anfang März bekannt wurde, gab es in den Vereinigten Arabischen Emiraten (UAE) zahlreiche Phantom-Distanzrennen, die in Wirklichkeit nicht stattgefunden haben sollen, deren Ergebnisse aber der FEI übermittelt worden sind die sogenannten bogus rides, gefälschte Ritte." ([St.Georg, 31.03.2015](http://www.st-georg.de/news/mehr-sport/distanz-skandale-weltmeister-sheik-maktoum-angeblich-im-zentrum-der-ermittlungen/))
- However, see also "Abstand" in the context of the long jump (Weitsprung).

Other examples of "Distanz" in the context of sports:

- "Doch Benedikt Höwedes köpfte nach Kroos-Ecke den Ball aus kurzer Distanz an den Pfosten." (Context: soccer; [Spiegel online, 14.07.2014](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/deutschland-ist-weltmeister-siegtor-durch-goetze-gegen-argentinien-a-980810.html))
- "Max Hopp besiegte Nathan Aspinall im Finale der Junioren Weltmeisterschaft 2015 mit 6:5. Die Auseinandersetzung war äußerst spannend und dauerte über die volle Distanz." (context: darts; "volle Distanz" here refers to efforts that need to be made for the entire duration of a tournament or match; [Darts1.de, no date](https://www.darts1.de/dart-wm/dart-weltmeister.php))
- "Ich verspreche aber, dass der Kampf nicht über die volle Distanz gehen wird. (...) Sobald er meine Power spürt, wird er nach einem Ausweg suchen." (context: boxing; [Boxen heute, 11.12.2013](http://www.boxen-heute.de/artikel/5041-alex-leapaikampf-gegen-klitschko-wird-nicht-ueber-die-volle-distanz-gehen.html))

Figurative use: "auf Distanz zu jmdm. gehen":

- "Frankreich geht auf Distanz zu al-Nusra in Syrien" ([Deutsche Wirtschaftsnachrichten, 14.07.2016](https://deutsche-wirtschafts-nachrichten.de/2016/07/14/frankreich-geht-aus-distanz-zu-al-nusra-in-syrien/))
- "Synode auf Distanz zu Luthers judenfeindlichen Äußerungen" ([T-Online.de, 19.11.2016](http://www.t-online.de/regionales/id_79594896/synode-auf-distanz-zu-luthers-judenfeindlichen-aeusserungen.html))

Other uses of "Distanz":

- "Drei Paare erzählen, wie sie ihren Alltag trotz Distanz miteinander teilen." (context: long-distance relationships; meaning: geographic distance; [Spiegel online, 07.11.2014](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/uni/fernbeziehung-wie-studenten-mit-liebe-auf-distanz-umgehen-a-1001210.html))
- "Die Distanz zwischen beiden Punkten ist dann die Länge dieses Vektors: (...)" (context: mathematics; "Distanz" here used as synonym for "Abstand": ["Abstand zwischen Punkten, Geraden und Ebenen", Mathematrix.de](http://www.mathematrix.de/abstand-punkt-gerade-ebene/))

**Entfernung**:

- "Wollen Sie die Entfernung zwischen zwei Orten berechnen?" (context: geography / transport; [EntfernungZwischenZweiOrten.de](http://www.entfernungzwischenzweiorten.de/)). The homepage goes on to say, "Für die Berechnung der Distanzen werden die Ortszentren als Ausgangspunkte verwendet.."
- "C# - Entfernung zwischen zwei geografischen Koordinaten berechnen" (context: geographic co-ordinates; [dotnet-snippets.de](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/entfernung-zwischen-zwei-geografischen-koordinaten-berechnen/828))
- "Aufgrund der großen Entfernung von Zweitwohnung und neuer Arbeitsstätte lehnte das Finanzamt das weitere Vorliegen einer doppelten Haushaltsführung ab. (...) Im vorliegenden Fall ist daher neben der reinen Entfernung und Fahrtzeit auch – wie vom Kläger vorgebracht – zu berücksichtigen, dass die räumliche Distanz durch die Verlagerung des Firmensitzes des Arbeitgebers verursacht wurde." (context: geographic distance; [BC – Zeitschrift für Bilanzierung, Rechnungswesen und Controlling, 2011](http://rsw.beck.de/CMS/?toc=BC.5202&docid=324457))
- "Doch Ralf Fährmann parierte beim Schuss aus kurzer Entfernung großartig, (...)" (context: soccer; [Web.de, 03.11.2016](https://web.de/magazine/sport/fussball/europa-league/europa-league-schalke-schafft-gruppensieg-eiltempo-31994340))

**Strecke**:

- "Viele Strecken in und um Nürnberg sind ideal zum Gehen, Walken, Laufen und Joggen. Die Laufparcours sind überwiegend asphaltiert und mit km-Angaben ausgeschildert." (context: running; [Sportservice Nürnberg](https://www.nuernberg.de/internet/sportservice_nbg/laufstrecken.html))

  - See also the words Laufstrecke and Joggingstrecke (jogging route).
- [Eisenbahnstrecke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenbahnstrecke) or Bahnstrecke: railway, e.g. "Die schönsten Eisenbahnstrecken der Schweiz" ([Railway Travel - Angebote der Bahnreisen durch die Schweiz](http://www.erlebnisreisen-schweiz.de/Sommerangebote/12-112-01.html))
- [Flugstrecke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flugstrecke): flight length / flight route, e.g. "Flugstrecken: „Meistbeflogene“ Wege in Europa" ([Focus online, 11.08.2009](http://www.focus.de/service/statistik/reisen-und-urlaub/flugstrecken-meistbeflogene-wege-in-europa_aid_425282.html))